# Problema con fetch_assoc()

Tags: php

Una consulta , alguien sabe que es lo que sucede con la variable `$result` después de hacer `$result->fetch_assoc()`

[image: Navegador]

[image: Codigo]

Comment: Y cuál sería el problema? Lo que indica pareciera una anomalía curiosa, pero no veo que sea un obstáculo para el código. ¿Qué pasa si en vez de `print_r` usas `var_dump`?

Comment: No es un problema es un detalle de `print_r` , debería emplear el  segundo parámetro true , `print_r($result,true)` para mostrar y poder concatenar el valor . si no solo mostrará true o 1

Comment: Hola Dev. Joel . Gracias por tu tiempo , pero no contesta mi pregunta .Saludos !

Comment: Haber , ahora pruebo lo del comentario ...

Comment: Tu problema no es tanto el `fetch_assoc`, sino esta función: `db_result_to_array`, la cual me parece que no pertenece al core de PHP. ¿Estás usando alguna función de terceros, muy probablemente del siglo pasado que hoy día no tiene ninguna utilidad y puede hacer tu código vulnerable? Si explicaras con más detalles lo que quieres hacer quizá podríamos proponerte un código de este siglo y que cubra posibles agujeros de seguridad muy graves.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano , es una funcion que saque de un libro , no se si del siglo pasado , pero si es un poco viejo . El proyecto trata sobre crear un carro de compra , y dentro de todo el codigo aparece esta funcion que no le termino de entender muy bien . Si quieres el codigo completo , con gusto te lo compartiria. Saludos !

Comment: Ten en cuenta que todo aquello menor a 18 años es del siglo pasado y puede que tu función lo sea. Al ver la imagen del código  me pareció redundante, ya que según el nombre la función crea un array de `$result` y también `fetch_assoc` crea un array de `$result`. Además, puede que dentro de `db_result_to_array` estés usando consultas vulnerables a la **inyección SQL**. Dado que tu problema fue resuelto, recomiendo que cuando puedas leas un poco sobre el tema y luego revises esa extraña función para ver sin cumple con esos criterios de seguridad. Saludos.

Comment: Bueno , por lo visto eres una persona que sabe mucho acerca del tema . ¿Que libro me recomiendas? . Gracias

Comment: Para inyección SQL, aquí mismo en Stackoverflow [hay varias preguntas/respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inyeccion+sql) que te pueden servir. Y en vez de libros, puedes ir consultado en mismo Manual de PHP, que está traducido al castellano. Por ejemplo para leer sobre el mismo tema [ver aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php). Y para conectar y consultar a la base de datos de forma segura, [recomendaría el uso de PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) es información amplia, por el momento con aprender a conectar y a consultar bastaría.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se desea concatenar lo que retorna la función [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) quizá deba especificar el segundo parámetro como `true` ya que esto hará que se devuelta un `String` y se realice la concatenación u asignar a una variable ,caso contrario devolverá `true` o `1`  , Lo correcto sería emplear esto de la siguiente forma.

```
echo "<p> Result antes" . print_r($result,true);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //{
echo "<p> Result despues" . print_r($result,true);
```

Comment: Se resolvio el problema , ya no muestra '1' . Gracias !

Comment: @Chehin qué bien. Si mi respuesta soluciono su problema puede aceptarla. Saludos.